# Using RewriteCond and RewriteRule to change my URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to use RewriteCond and RewriteRule to change automatically the URL from one place to a new one.

That's my attempt:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?option=com_sobipro&pid=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /component/sobipro/%2 [R=301,L]
```

I need to change this: http://www.idermo.es/index.php?option=com_sobipro&pid=1&sid=14408

To this: http://www.idermo.es/component/sobipro/14408.html

As you can see, I only have to get the number to put it in the new URL, but I can't make this work. Can you help me, please?

At the moment it's only showing this: idermo.es/component/sobipro/1&sid=14408?option=com_sobipro&pid=1&sid=14408

**Edit:**

I have change the place where my "entries" are stored (Joomla) and the URL like "idermo.es/index.php?option=com_sobipro&pid=1&sid=14408" is no longer active, but some users may be using it (because they are inside QR codes printed) and I want those users to be redirected to the new ones like "idermo.es/component/sobipro/14408" URL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_sobipro.*&sid=(\d+)
RewriteRule index.php$ /component/sobipro/%1? [R,L]
```

This will inspect the query string to make sure it matches `option=com_sobipro` and grab the number following `sid`

Comment: Hi @arco444, it's not working, my URL is showing only "idermo.es/component/sobipro/" without the number at the end. Thanks.

Comment: My mistake, got the backreference wrong - it should be `%1` not `$1` - see the edited answer.